# How can i do test in redux-sagas

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

I'm using firebase, and so I'm putting `auth` as a dependency injection. In my sagas i have this code:

```
export function* isAuth(auth) {
try{
    const wrapper = {
        authFunction : () => auth.currentUser
    }
    const {authFunction} = wrapper
    const user = yield call([wrapper, authFunction])

    if (user !== null){
        yield put(ActionCreator.authSuccess(user))
    } 
}catch({message}){
    yield put(ActionCreator.authFailure(message))
} 
}
```

and in my file of test i have this code:

```
describe('should test isAuth', () => { 
const auth = {currentUser: {}}
const {currentUser} = auth
const authMock = {
    authFunction: () => currentUser
}
const {authFunction} = authMock 
const it = sagaHelper(isAuth(authMock))
it('should call api authFunction', result => {
    expect(result).toEqual(call([authMock, authFunction]))
    return {
        user: undefined
    }
})
it('should put authSuccess', result => {
    expect(result).toEqual(put(ActionCreator.authSuccess(undefined)))
})
})
```

This should work, because the saga works normally, but the following error appears:

```
should test isAuth › should call api authFunction

expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "CALL": {"args": [], "context": {"authFunction": [Function authFunction]}, "fn": [Function authFunction]}}
Received:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "CALL": {"args": [], "context": {"authFunction": [Function authFunction]}, "fn": [Function authFunction]}}

Difference:

Compared values have no visual difference.
```

Anyone know how I could solve this problem? I've been trying to fix this all day but it does not work.

Comment: What is `it` here? Is it the `it` of jest or your definition of `it`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expect(JSON.stringify(result)).toEqual(
  JSON.stringify(call([authMock, authFunction]))
);
```

Comment: My understanding is that the values being compared may not seem the same for jest, although they are visually the same.  More information can be found in https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5998.